# Enter key not working on with in an html code for login

Tags: html

I am making a html page where you login to see links but I cant get the enter key working

```
<form name = "myform">
<p style="text-align:center">ENTER USERNAME <input type="text" name="username"></p> 
<p style="text-align:center">ENTER PASSWORD <input type="password" name="pword"></p>
<p style="text-align:center"><input type="button" value="Check In" name="Submit" onclick= "validate()">
</p></center>
```

Comment: Can you please post the code that you are using to make this?

Comment: Hay Vic the code has been posted

Comment: I added an answer but it's pretty much the same as darkhouse. Notice that both answers remove the style elements, it's always best if you can control the style with CSS instead of html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your enter button to work, you need to change your button input type to submit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="action_page">
            Username:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username">
            <br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="password" name="pword">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form> 
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: No problem. Make sure to upvote the answer that was useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted Darkhouse's answer but wanted to post this most simple version of your code that should also work just fine:

```
<form name = "myform">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
  <input type="password" name="pword" placeholder="Enter Password">
  <input type="submit" value="Check In" name="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: is there a way to link a html to a database without PHP

Comment: yes, it just depends on what kind of system you are working in. For sql php works fine, but if you are converting into a json and storing in a nosql like mongodb you wouldn't use php.

Comment: If you are using an SQL db then php will work, but I'm no php guru